# Drawing PyQt Painter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, graphic

I'm trying to draw a map with pyqt and it does not work. So far either I have no output or I get errors like Seg fault.

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Painel')
        list_ = []
        file_ = open('points.txt')
        for line in file_.readlines():
            l = line.replace("\n", "")
            l = l.split(" ")
            try:
                l = [float(i) for i in l]
                list_.append(l)
            except: pass#possible strings
        first = list_[0]
        list_ = list_[1:]
        self.path = QPainterPath()
        self.path.moveTo(*first)
        for i in list_:
            self.path.lineTo(*i)

    def paintEvent(self, e):      
        qp = QPainter()

        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawPath(self.path)
        qp.end()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
ex.show()
app.exec_()
```

[Edit] And here is some of the content of points.txt

```
-57.328 -29.972
-57.323 -29.937
-57.329 -29.895
-57.328 -29.880
-57.295 -29.832
-57.242 -29.789
-57.227 -29.780
-57.171 -29.781
-57.134 -29.771
```

And I'm using mac os 10.6.7 & active python 2.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Python 2.6.6 on old Debian stable.

You'll need to offset negative numbers to make them positive, or they'll render "offscreen" and won't be visible in your app.

Comment: Oh, this is for the rest of the code. still, taking that line away does not make the paintEvent to draw the path.

Comment: what is the stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: Oh that worked. These points worked for a Java version of this software. Thank you.